# JSON conversion with R package jsonlite

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I have to convert a JSON string into a R object, add some information and convert it back to a JSON string.

I managed to use the package jsonlite on simple examples but now I have an issue with the "not so complex" string
`{"A":["a"], "B":true}`, ie if I do:

`jsonlite::toJSON (jsonlite::fromJSON ('{"A":["a"], "B":true}') )`

then I get:

`{"A":["a"], "B":[true]}`

which is not the same as the initial string since the second value has been put into a vector.

My question is:
**is there a way to make jsonlite get back to the initial string ?**

Answer (score 3):

For this specific case, you could set the toJSON's `auto_unbox` to TRUE and the fromJSON's `simplifyVector` to FALSE.

```
jsonlite::toJSON (x = jsonlite::fromJSON ('{"A":["a"], "B":true}', 
                                          simplifyVector = FALSE), 
                  auto_unbox = TRUE)

#{"A":["a"],"B":true}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to alter the object. Pretty much everything in R is a vector. So when you have character values and logical values, those are all vectors. When you are making JSON strings, you can either set it to "auto unbox" vectors of length 1 to not use array brackets or you have have all vectors use array brackets. Since you want different behaviors for the string values and the logical values, there's no way for  `toJSON` to guess what you want.

You can be more explicit using the `unbox()` function

```
jsonlite::toJSON(list(A = "a", B = jsonlite::unbox(TRUE)))
# {"A":["a"],"B":true}
```

Here we explictly unbox the `B` value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand that point, the issue is that I receive JSON strings from a server such as those I gave as example; the only thing I can do is to call fromJSON first and then the issue arises.